# Localization For Two Different Regions/Domains with the Same Language

Tags: custom-post-types, customization, domain, domain-mapping

I have a site which is based in US (ex. www.example.com). We've been tasked to create a UK/GB version of the site which has it's own domain (ex. www.example.co.uk), but shares the same common pages/posts/backend. About 75% of the pages are the same on both versions but there will be a few sections (like About and Contact) where they are different to account for regional differences.

**Example**

US site (www.example.com) has 4 Pages:

- **Home**
- **About**
- **Services**
- **Contact**

UK Site (www.example.co.uk) also has 3 pages (2 different, 1 the same)

- **Home** (The same as US, but the URL should be www.example.co.uk)
- **About** (Different content, the URL should be www.example.co.uk/about)
- **Services** (The same as US, but URL should be www.example.co.uk/services)
- **Contact** (Different content, the URL should be www.example.co.uk/contact)

How do I go about setting up the UK/GB version of the site which use the same backend and most of the same content from the base site, but has a few page differences and different domain?

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to use WordPress MU Domain Mapping Plugin:

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-mu-domain-mapping/

But, isn't this a bad idea from a search engine perspective? Multiple domains each with the same content?

Comment: Yea, the SEO thing is a problem, but I can't think of a better solution. The UK needs it's own regionalized site, but has 95% of the same content. maybe someone else might have a better solution

Answer (score 0):

This is just a suggestion and I'm not sure if it would work but how about this:

Use a plugin like http://wpml.org/

.com points to en_US language and .co.uk points to en_GB language. So for pages where you need a UK and US versions you just create translations for those posts/pages

Comment: Also WPML can be got free before it became premium plugin here: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/sitepress-multilingual-cms/ although it might not work with the latest version of wordpress

Comment: Does WPML have URL routing? I went through the plugin, but it didn't seem to have any configuration options for that

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you decide upon `echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];` (and else) what content/nav_menu you want to display?

Comment: Can you elaborate on this?

Comment: I guess this [1] link will tell you most. Simply do `if ( $_SERVER['whatever'] ) : /* do stuff */ endif;` [1] http://php.net/manual/de/reserved.variables.server.php